# Swift how to send request from one application to another

Tags: ios, swift

I'am fairly new to Swift programming language. Currently working on developing two iOS applications, the first is named GenieSugar Diabetic, and the other is named GenieSugar Physician. As the names indicate, these applications are developed to monitor a diabetic patient health state by his/her physician. As a part of this system, I want to implement a feature by which the diabetic sends an appointment request to his/her doctor, and then the doctor receives that request then sends back the appointment details (time,date,...), after that, the.

Now my question is, I don't have any idea of how to handle such processes,

How to send the request?
How to receive and display the request on the physician's application?
How to send the appointment confirmation to the patient app?

I'm not asking for codes, just want to get an idea of how to handle that -logically-?

thanks in advance

Comment: [This](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html) article about inter app communication may help you out

Comment: You can use URL Schemes: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes--mobile-6629

Comment: Use apple push notification service.

Comment: Thanks too much, push notification service is a good solution, thanks again,